# Is it possible to end a function that is placed within a loop from outside the loop?

Tags: c, glfw

How might I end a function after it has been called once within a `do...while` loop? For example, in the below code, I would want `myfunc()` to be called only once, then not be called again within the loop. Is that possible?

```
        do{
            myfunc();

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(0, fb_width, fb_height, 0, 0, 1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            drawSomething();

            glfwSwapBuffers(w);
            glfwPollEvents();
          }
        while (something);
```

Comment: Why not put it before the loop starts, or is your actual code more complex than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either yo can put it before the do while loop

or you can hold a flag variable that store whether the function has already been executed or not.

```
int flag = 0;

do {

    if(flag==0){
        myfunc();
        flag=1;
    }
    ... // Rest of the loop

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Commonly one can do it using a static variable which counts the first pass. The implementation can depend on whether it's within a call or within a callback.

```
static int first = 0;

do{
   if(!first){
      myfunc();
      first = 1;
      }
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   // the rest of your code

}while something;

first = 0; //or not zero it if you want to remember the state
```